# Why is the Unresolved Dependencies error with SecureSocial and Play 2.3.2?

Tags: java, scala, sbt, playframework-2.3, securesocial

i'm writing a Play 2.3.2 application (using Java).
In my project now i need to use secure social (master) module.
But when i type the activator run command i get the following errors:

```
[info] Resolving ws.securesocial#securesocial_2.11;1.0-SNAPSHOT ...
[warn]  module not found: ws.securesocial#securesocial_2.11;1.0-SNAPSHOT
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /home/giacomo/.ivy2/local/ws.securesocial/securesocial_2.11/1.0-SNAPSHOT/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== activator-local: tried
[warn]   file:/home/giacomo/stage/bdrim/repository/ws.securesocial/securesocial_2.11/1.0-SNAPSHOT/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ws/securesocial/securesocial_2.11/1.0-SNAPSHOT/securesocial_2.11-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[warn] ==== typesafe-releases: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/ws/securesocial/securesocial_2.11/1.0-SNAPSHOT/securesocial_2.11-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releasez: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/ws.securesocial/securesocial_2.11/1.0-SNAPSHOT/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== Typesafe Releases Repository: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/ws/securesocial/securesocial_2.11/1.0-SNAPSHOT/securesocial_2.11-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[warn] ==== sonatype-snapshots: tried
[warn]   https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/ws/securesocial/securesocial_2.11/1.0-SNAPSHOT/securesocial_2.11-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[warn] ==== SecureSocial Repository: tried
[warn]   http://securesocial.ws/repository/snapshots/ws.securesocial/securesocial_2.11/1.0-SNAPSHOT/ivys/ivy.xml
[info] Resolving jline#jline;2.11 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: ws.securesocial#securesocial_2.11;1.0-SNAPSHOT: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last *:update for the full output.
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: ws.securesocial#securesocial_2.11;1.0-SNAPSHOT: not found
[error] Total time: 9 s, completed Sep 25, 2014 4:01:16 PM
```

This is my build.sbt file:

```
name := "BigDataAnalysis"

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)

scalaVersion := "2.11.1"

resolvers ++= Seq(
    Resolver.sonatypeRepo("snapshots"),
    Resolver.url("SecureSocial Repository", url("http://securesocial.ws/repository/snapshots/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)
)

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  javaEbean,
  cache,
  javaWs,
  javaCore,
  "ws.securesocial" %% "securesocial" % version.value,
  "commons-collections" % "commons-collections" % "3.2.1",
  "commons-io" % "commons-io" % "2.4",
  "org.mongodb" % "mongo-java-driver" % "2.12.1",
  "org.jongo" % "jongo" % "1.0",
  "org.mindrot" % "jbcrypt" % "0.3m"
)

javaOptions in Test += "-Dconfig.file=conf/test.conf"
```

What's wrong?? Nobody can help me??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never used SecureSocial before, so I can't promise a definitive answer, but there appear to be two problems.

First of all, it appears as though the second URL you're using for the Maven repository is incorrect (http://securesocial.ws/repository/snapshots/ results in a 404). That's not the fatal error though, because according to [the docs](http://securesocial.ws/guide/installation.html), SecureSocial is in Maven Central.

The second, larger problem is that you appear to be requesting a version of SecureSocial to match the version of your own project (`"ws.securesocial" %% "securesocial" % version.value`). You probably don't want to do this, unless you want to pin your project's versioning to SecureSocial.

It may resolve your issue to use one of the library dependency strings referred to in SecureSocial's docs:

`"ws.securesocial" %% "securesocial" % "2.1.4"` if you want the latest version, or `"ws.securesocial" %% "securesocial" % "master-SNAPSHOT"` if you want the latest snapshot.