# Unresolved dependency error with SecureSocial

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, sbt, securesocial

I require Secure Social Plugin [http://securesocial.ws/guide/installation.html ] for my project. When I run the play 2 app I am getting the following error.

I also referred the following post: [Why is the Unresolved Dependencies error with SecureSocial and Play 2.3.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26040772/why-is-the-unresolved-dependencies-error-with-securesocial-and-play-2-3-2)

```
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: ws.securesocial#securesocial;2.1.4: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency:ws.securesocial#securesocial;2.1.4: not found
at sbt.IvyActions$.sbt$IvyActions$$resolve(IvyActions.scala:217)
at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$update$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:126)
at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$update$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:125)
at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:115)
at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:115)
at sbt.IvySbt$$anonfun$withIvy$1.apply(Ivy.scala:103)
at sbt.IvySbt.sbt$IvySbt$$action$1(Ivy.scala:48)
at sbt.IvySbt$$anon$3.call(Ivy.scala:57)
at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:93)
at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:81)
at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:102)
at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:11)
at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:10)
at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:62)
at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:52)
at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
at sbt.IvySbt.withDefaultLogger(Ivy.scala:57)
at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:98)
at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:94)
at sbt.IvySbt$Module.withModule(Ivy.scala:115)
at sbt.IvyActions$.update(IvyActions.scala:125)
at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1223)
at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1221)
at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$74.apply(Defaults.scala:1244)
at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$74.apply(Defaults.scala:1242)
at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$lastOutput$1.apply(Tracked.scala:35)
at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1246)
at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1241)
at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$inputChanged$1.apply(Tracked.scala:45)
at sbt.Classpaths$.cachedUpdate(Defaults.scala:1249)
at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1214)
at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1192)
at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:42)
at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:64)
at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:18)
at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:244)
at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:160)
at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:30)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: ws.securesocial#securesocial;2.1.4: not found
[error] Total time: 14 s, completed 8 Mar, 2015 9:22:50 AM

Process finished with exit code 1
```

This is my build.sbt file

```
name := "testing"

version := "0.1"

lazy val `testing` = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)

scalaVersion := "2.11.1"

resolvers ++= Seq(
Resolver.sonatypeRepo("snapshots"),
Resolver.url("SecureSocial Repository", url("http://securesocial.ws/repository/snapshots/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)
)

libraryDependencies ++= Seq( javaJdbc , javaEbean , cache , javaWs,
"ws.securesocial" % "securesocial" % "2.1.4",
"org.mongodb" % "mongo-java-driver" % "2.12.1",
"org.jongo" % "jongo" % "1.1")

unmanagedResourceDirectories in Test <+=  baseDirectory ( _    /"target/web/public/test" )
```

Am I missing something? Can anyone help me out with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed "ws.securesocial" % "securesocial" % "2.1.4" to "ws.securesocial" % "securesocial_2.11" % "3.0-M3"

```
name := "testing"

version := "0.1"

lazy val `testing` = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)

scalaVersion := "2.11.1"

resolvers += (
  Resolver.url("SecureSocial Repository", url("http://securesocial.ws/repository/snapshots/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)
)


libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
"ws.securesocial" % "securesocial_2.11" % "3.0-M3",
"org.mongodb" % "mongo-java-driver" % "2.12.1",
"org.jongo" % "jongo" % "1.1")

unmanagedResourceDirectories in Test <+=  baseDirectory ( _ /"target/web/public/test" )
```

Check this link for the sample implementation in java and scala.
https://github.com/jaliss/securesocial/tree/master/samples